# How to If statement float comparison in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

i want to comapare two array. kor,eng
each array consists of cid,mapx,mapy.

[image]

is kor

[image]

is eng
i want to append list.

```
if eng(mapx)==kor(mapx) && eng(mapy)==kor(mpay):
      newlist.append(kor(cid),eng(cid))
```

so i write a code

```
for i in eng:
    for k in kor:
        if eng[i][1]==kor[k][1] and eng[i][2]==kor[k][2]:
            samedata.append((eng[i][0],kor[i][0]))
```

but IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

how to compare and append?..

Comment: You try to index list with a list: eng[i][1] (i is a list in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over an array, you get its values directly, not indices, here `i` and `k` are the different arrays that composed `eng` and `kor`

```
for sub_eng in eng:
    for sub_kor in kor:
        if sub_eng[1] == sub_kor[1] and sub_eng[2] == sub_kor[2]:
            samedata.append(sub_eng[0],sub_kor[0]))
```

But as the size is known you can directly unpack to `cid,mapx,mapy`

```
for c_eng, x_eng, y_eng in eng:
    for c_kor, x_kor, y_kor in kor:
        if x_eng == x_kor and y_eng == y_kor:
            samedata.append(c_eng, c_kor))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing 2 different types of for loops. It either has to be:

```
for i in range(len(eng)):
    for k in range(len(kor)):
        if eng[i][1]==kor[k][1] and eng[i][2]==kor[k][2]:
            samedata.append((eng[i][0],kor[i][0]))
```

OR:

```
for i in eng:
    for k in kor:
        if i[1]==k[1] and i[2]==k[2]:
            samedata.append((eng[i][0],kor[i][0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
def appendList(list1, list2):
    return set(list1) & set(list2)

print(appendList([1,2,3],[5,2,3]))
```

This will not only compare but also append the two arrays or list in this case by using that function.